# Sphinx parent class in another package: how to disable single backtick reference warnings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, numpydoc

I am working on implementing a Python package that inherits from [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx). Networkx seems to use `numpydoc`, but also wraps certain parts of their docstrings in single backtick characters: `` ` ``. This normally in rst files denotes italics, but in `numpydoc` this attempts to create a reference.

So when I have a file like the following where I use `autodoc`'s `autosummary` directive:

```
.. currentmodule:: pywhy_graphs.classes.timeseries

.. autosummary:: 
   :toctree: generated/
   
   TimeSeriesGraph
   TimeSeriesDiGraph
   TimeSeriesMixedEdgeGraph
```

I get the following errors (I copy-pasted only 3 examples for the sake of space):

```
/Users/adam2392/Documents/pywhy-graphs/pywhy_graphs/classes/timeseries/timeseries.py:docstring of networkx.classes.graph.Graph.to_undirected:33: WARNING: py:obj reference target not found: G = nx.DiGraph(D)
/Users/adam2392/Documents/pywhy-graphs/pywhy_graphs/classes/timeseries/timeseries.py:docstring of networkx.classes.graph.Graph.update:25: WARNING: py:obj reference target not found: edges is None
/Users/adam2392/Documents/pywhy-graphs/pywhy_graphs/classes/timeseries/timeseries.py:docstring of networkx.classes.graph.Graph.update:25: WARNING: py:obj reference target not found: nodes is None
```

These come for example from docstrings like: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/83948b6dc61f507adb4cd1a71561eac9ed3b72ec/networkx/classes/graph.py#L1183.

#### Questions

1. If I am using numpydoc, why am I getting this error, but networkx does not when building docs with sphinx?
2. How do I disable, or workaround this error?
3. I don't understand what is going on. If someone can help elaborate what I should do and why, that would be very helpful in learning Sphinx/numpydoc.

Comment: I have no idea, but if I were inheriting the documentation from another package, I would following their installation instructions https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/doc/README.md

Comment: NetworkX docs sets `obj` as the default role: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/doc/conf.py#L238

Comment: I installed the package following their instructions. I tried setting `nitpicky=False` and there was no change. I'm also not sure why `NetworkX docs sets obj as the default role:` matters?

Comment: The issue is that `networkx` somehow doesn't treat these backticks as references, whereas normal numpydoc does.

Comment: Setting `obj` as the default role turns all strings enclosed in backticks into cross-references. `\`abc\`` is interpreted as `:obj:\`abc\``.

Comment: And `obj` is the default role in numpydoc as well: https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/blob/main/numpydoc/xref.py#L100

Comment: But `networkx` does not contain any errors when I build their documentation w/ numpydoc, so I'm confused how that is possible.

Comment: It is easy to generate the warning messages you are getting (with `nitpicky = True`). Setting `nitpicky = False` does not work for you apparently. I am stumped.

Comment: I've been using Sphinx for 10+ years and I still don't know how to fix this issue properly.